# Rails: How to implement AJAX for will_paginate

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

When I am on tab 2 and I click for example on page 3, it refreshes the page and then I am back at tab 1. My guess is that I need AJAX to fix this problem, but I could use some help with that.

I tried some examples before, but none of them work.

Please help me how to sole this. Thank you in advance!

**Controller:**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @fullname = current_user.first_name + " " + current_user.last_name
    @recipes = current_user.recipes.page(params[:recipes_page]).order("created_at DESC")
    @favorites = current_user.favorites.page(params[:favorites_page]).order("created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

**Inside my view:**

```
<div class="apple_pagination">
  <%= will_paginate @recipes, param_name: "recipes_page" %>
</div>

<div class="apple_pagination">
  <%= will_paginate @favorites, param_name: "favorites_page" %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="apple_pagination">
  <%= will_paginate @recipes, :remote => true , param_name: "recipes_page" %>
</div>

<div class="apple_pagination">
  <%= will_paginate @favorites, :remote => true , param_name: "favorites_page" %>
</div>
```